# grails return empty properties values from application.yml file

Tags: grails

I have a file grails-app/conf/application.yml
having these properties

```
facebook.login.success=loginSuccess
facebook.login.failure=loginFailed
```

I am calling from controller

```
String success = grailsApplication.config.facebook.login.success

 String fail    = grailsApplication.config.facebook.login.failure
```

but these properties are empty.
Why grails is not getting these properties from application.yml

GRAILS version : 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Grails 2.5.0 doesn't support YAML. You should configure your application using

```
grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
grails-app/conf/Config.groovy
```

See the [Grails 2.5.0 configuration guide](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/conf.html#config) for a wider explanation.